# Trying to load an element from another site

Tags: jquery, load, external

I'm trying to load a table from another site.

```
<tbody style="{$expdisplay} width:auto; height: auto;" id="cat_serverboards_e"></tbody>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script>$( "#cat_serverboards_e" ).load('http://unidentifiedgaming.net/serversboard.php #serversboard_e');</script>
```

For reference: http://unidentifiedgaming.net/serversboard.php#serversboard_e

From google searches this should work in theory but for some reason it isn't.

Any insight would be great.

What I'm looking for:

[image]

Comment: Just to add, the web host will not allow out going game server queries, and the host that will, doesn't allow web service on port 80